# java.io.FileNotFoundException: resourceedge-config.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java

I was using jboss server to deploy my applications and it works fine. My jboss server is corrupted, and I'm changing to tomcat 7.0.55 and its giving me error on my console

```
"java.io.FileNotFoundException: resourceedge-config.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)"
```

The resourceedge-config.xml is readingfrom this method:

```
public static Properties loadSystemConfiguration() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    return loadSystemConfiguration(ConfigReader.getFile_Prefix() + "-config.xml");
}
```

And it's also calling from my application filter class too which is:

//get the application context

```
    ServletContext context = filterConfig.getServletContext();

    String configFilePrefix = context.getInitParameter(ApplicationFilter.APPLICATION_CONFIG_FILE_PREFIX);
    if(configFilePrefix != null){
        ConfigReader.setFile_Prefix(configFilePrefix);
    }
    try{
        configuration = ConfigReader.loadSystemConfiguration();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        configuration = null;
    }
```

`The resourceedge-config.xml is place inside C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\bin`

Please I need help on this to enable to read the file resourceedge-config.xml.

Thanks